# Save Generated PDF file into Solution's folder in C#

Tags: c#, windows-services, filestream

I want to Download the Generated file into My Window Web Service's Solutions folder.

I am using some code like::

```
   public void PrintInvoice(long ID)
        {

            ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
            rd.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+(@"\Reports\InvoiceDocument.rpt"));
            ConnectionInfo ConnInfo = new ConnectionInfo { ServerName = "ServerName", UserID = "UserID", Password = "Password", DatabaseName = "DatabaseName" };
            rd.SetParameterValue("InvoiceNumber", 56);
                Stream stream = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                return File(stream, "application/pdf", "TestCrystal.pdf");     
        }
```

Here I want to save the generated PDF file into the Folder 'App_Data' made into the solution itself.
what can I do in my code for saving that PDF file into solution's 'App_Data' named folder?

Comment: What is a `window web service`?

Comment: Solution's are a development/compile time concept. They don't really exist as a concept at runtime.

Comment: ok my fault,  
But what can I do here to save the file which is in stream?